# Update TextView in a RecyclerView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have fetched data from Firebase and displaying it in a RecyclerView. It is a cart fragment, I want to add the functionality of increase/ decrease an item. How can I update the REcyclerView so that specific item in an RecyclerView gets updated?
The TextView I want to update is "medicine_result_qty_id" present in RecyclerView.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, ItemViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, ItemViewHolder>(firebaseRecycleroption)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Item model)
        {
            holder.setDetails(model.getName(),model.getPharmacy(), model.getCost(), model.getQty(), model.getTotalStock());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            holder.increaseQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Increase quantity
                    int maximumLimit = model.getTotalStock();

                }
            });

            holder.decreaseQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Decrease quantity

                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.cart_list_layout, parent, false);

            ItemViewHolder viewHolder= new ItemViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    cartRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

I want to update the value in this function:

```
holder.increaseQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Increase quantity
                int maximumLimit = model.getTotalStock();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to add the textView and setter function in the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout root;
    public TextView medicineQty;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        root = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_root);
        medicineQty= itemView.findViewById(R.id.medicine_result_qty_id);
    }

    public void setMedicineQty(String string) {
        medicineQty.setText(string);
    }

}
```

And back in your adapter add:

```
holder.increaseQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.setMedicineQty("Whatever you want to set the text to here")
               
                //Increase quantity
                int maximumLimit = model.getTotalStock();

            }
        });
```